# Find the original record and change only that not the inserted one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, triggers

I have tried it but not successful so far. Since my knowledge in query is limited, I thought I will better post it here.

I have students table with the following structure

```
create table students(
id int not null primary key identity,
sname varchar(25),
status varchar(25),
renew varchar(15),
enrollment datetime,
)
```

I have a number of students who has an ID, studentName(sname),status('active' or 'not-active'), renew('no' for new student, yes' for renewed student) and enrollment date.

```
insert into students values('jay','active','no','2010-01-01')
insert into students values('Phil','active','no','2010-01-01')
insert into students values('Cru','active','no','2010-01-01')
insert into students values('slow','active','no','2010-01-01')
insert into students values('true','active','no','2010-01-01')
insert into students values('false','active','no','2010-01-01')
```

Now I have an INSERT Trigger which is suppose to deactive an old student when a student is renewed. So if I insert the following which has renewal set to 'yes', it should make the already existing record 'inactive'.

```
insert into students values('false','active','yes','2011-01-01')
```

I wrote this INSERT Trigger and it works but it in-actives the old and the new inserted record both. I want only the original record to be inactivated. Also not that only enrollment date and nenew fields are different, the rest are the same between original and insert records. How to fix this? Here is my trigger

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_renew_student]
ON [dbo].students
-- WITH ENCRYPTION
FOR INSERT
-- WITH APPEND
-- NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
-- insert sql here
if exists(select * from inserted where Renew = 'yes')
BEGIN

UPDATE students 
    SET status = 'Inactive'

    FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN students T2
            ON i.sname = T2.sname

END
```

Note that this is close approximation to my problem. Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at @@identity?  Years back I dealt with something similar and used @@identity to get the last created identity value; basically getting the latest identity value then setting all the records matching the criteria except the one with the ID returned via @@identity.

Read about the identity value getters here:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

**Added**:  You're right about the `inserted` table.  If you didn't want to / can't use the inserted table, your trigger could look something like this.

```
SELECT @@identity //  <- this gets the last identity value inserted.

UPDATE students
SET status = 'Inactive'
WHERE students.name = (SELECT name FROM students WHERE id = @@identity)
  AND id <> @@identity
```

Note: written from memory and not tested.

Comment: I think the last inserted record does not provide the solution. `Inserted` table has everything that I need to join with the original table and find the actual record that I need to modify.

Comment: I don't typically work with triggers so Inserted slipped my mind earlier.  See my updated answer for more details on what I was thinking for an approach.

Answer (score 1):

Change your update to this:

```
UPDATE students 
    SET status = 'Inactive'

    FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN students T2
            ON i.sname = T2.sname
            AND i.id <> t2.id
```

This checks that the row you are updating is NOT the newly inserted row.

Comment: question: how will it make sure it will update the original record, not the insert one? It did the trick by the way

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - because you are making sure the `Id`, which is auto-generated on insert, does not match the `id` for the new row.

Comment: This works OK in my test example but in my actual code, it works the other way around. The row is updated in the INSERTED table not the one that needs to be updated.

Comment: Well then show your actual code.  How are we supposed to help you when you don't give accurate examples?

Comment: Of course it is a project, your solution work in this sample but not in the actual code. It has the same ID field just like here. My orig question was: what is the logic that it will not updated the insert record? Because there does not seem to be a firm logic. It can go either way?